# ignite client returns : Failed to establish connection with any host

Tags: ignite

I am new to ignite and I am trying to run this simple example.
I run a node with this configuration

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide a list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>198.168.0.1:47500..47502</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

after that I am trying to run

```
IgniteClientConfiguration mConfiguration;
mConfiguration.SetEndPoints("198.168.0.1:47500..47502");
        mClient = IgniteClient::Start(mConfiguration);
```

but Start is throwing and exception **Failed to establish connection with any host**
Does anybody know why ? I am running my node and program under the same machine ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it happens because you are trying to connect a .NET thin client to a discovery port (it's for thick clients and servers). Try this one (10800 is the default thin client port):
`mConfiguration.SetEndPoints("198.168.0.1:10800");`

This one (with the `localhost`) will work for example if you wish to connect to a node deployed locally.

Comment: I still have the same issue with the address you proposed . the only address that worked is localhost I think that we should mention the address of the machine on which the node is deployed.

Comment: @AnisBelaid do you have your node and client running on the same machine?

Comment: yes I do, they are running under the same machine.

Comment: And now when I am trying to get values from the cache the nodes with the localhost address returns empty ones.